# get dataframe of groupby where all column entries are null

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am using pyspark 2.4.5 and have a dataframe which I have already filtered to contain all entries as part of a groupby that contain null values

```
df_nulls = df.where(reduce(lambda x, y: x | y, (col(c).isNull() for c in df.columns)))
```

From this I want to filter further to remove (and get a separate dataframe) of all entries where all columns had null values.

At the moment I was able to achieve this for one column by checking if the min and max of this column are both null and returning a 1 or 0 based on this

```
agg_expression = [when((min(c).eqNullSafe(max(c))).alias(c) , 1).otherwise(0).alias(c) for c in columns]

df_run_all_nulls = df_nulls.groupby("cat1", "cat2", "cat3", "cat4").agg(*agg_expression)
```

I can then filter further on this dataframe to get the entries relating to null or non null values

```
df_run_all_nulls.where(df_run_all_nulls.col1 == 1).count()
```

I could loop through and get this information for each column I have in the dataset (I am interested in the overlap of all nulls between different columns), but would like to know if there is a better / smarter way to do something like this?

Id also want to know if there are any entries where all columns are null.

A sample dataframe of my initial data looks like

```
| cat1 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| 1    | 1    | null | null | null | 
| 1    | 2    | null | null | null |
| 2    | 1    | 50   | 0.3  | 2    |
| 2    | 2    | 60   | 0.3  | 6    |
| 1    | 3    | null | null | null |
| 3    | 1    | null | 10   | null |
| 3    | 2    | null | 2    | 2    |
| 3    | 3    | null | 20   | 4    |
```

where cat1 indicates a grouping (in my case a running process), col1 indicates a timestep, which can be of varying length depending on which process is running, cols 2 & 3 are then sensor readings taking at each timestep during this process.

So I would like to extract two dataframes from the above, one which just includes processes where all the sensor data was null but there will be columns here which by default always log data, so the null check should be on a subset of columns.

```
| cat1 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| 1    | 1    | null | null | null | 
| 1    | 2    | null | null | null |
| 1    | 3    | null | null | null |
```

Here actually just a list of unique cat1 entries would suffice, in this case [1] (but more would be found in reality)

The second dataframe should then just contain processes where some of the data contained null values.

```
| cat1 | col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 |
| 3    | 1    | null | 10   | null |
| 3    | 2    | null | 2    | 2    |
| 3    | 3    | null | 20   | 4    |
```

Comment: woops, sorry!  I updated the table now to show both possible null cases.  Process 1 where everything (except the timestamp is null) and process 3 where only some recordings are null.

Comment: just to be clear, your problem is not about groupBy. You do not really group anything, you just select lines where you have nulls for a specific ID.

Comment: In the first example I would want all of the entries per group to have null values, maybe I phrased the question wrong.  I thought because I need all the entries per group / category to be null that this would probably be achieved with a group by.  But if there is a better / different way to do it that is also fine, I just wasn't sure on the terminology.

Comment: What is your spark version ?

Comment: The pyspark is 2.4.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try this with some [`Window`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.7/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Window) functions:

```py
from functools import reduce

from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window as W


exclude_cols = ["cat1", "col1"]

df = reduce(
    lambda a, b: a.withColumn(b["colName"], b["col"]),
    [
        {
            "colName": f"{col}_grp",
            "col": F.max(F.when(F.col(col).isNotNull(), 1).otherwise(0)).over(
                W.partitionBy("cat1")
            ),
        }
        for col in df.columns
        if col not in exclude_cols
    ],
    df,
)

df.show()
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+
|cat1|col1|col2|col3|col4|col2_grp|col3_grp|col4_grp|
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+
|   1|   1|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   1|   2|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   1|   3|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   3|   1|null|10.0|null|       0|       1|       1|
|   3|   2|null| 2.0|   2|       0|       1|       1|
|   3|   3|null|20.0|   4|       0|       1|       1|
|   2|   2|  60| 0.3|   6|       1|       1|       1|
|   2|   1|  50| 0.3|   2|       1|       1|       1|
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

from this dataframe, you can select the lines you need with a simple where :

```
# first dataframe 
df.where(
    F.greatest(*(F.col(col) for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_grp"))) == 0
).show()
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+                           
|cat1|col1|col2|col3|col4|col2_grp|col3_grp|col4_grp|
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+
|   1|   1|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   1|   2|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   1|   3|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+

# second one (which theoretically should include ID 1 also)
df.where(
    F.least(*(F.col(col) for col in df.columns if col.endswith("_grp"))) == 0
).show()
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+                           
|cat1|col1|col2|col3|col4|col2_grp|col3_grp|col4_grp|
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+
|   1|   1|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   1|   2|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   1|   3|null|null|null|       0|       0|       0|
|   3|   1|null|10.0|null|       0|       1|       1|
|   3|   2|null| 2.0|   2|       0|       1|       1|
|   3|   3|null|20.0|   4|       0|       1|       1|
+----+----+----+----+----+--------+--------+--------+
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it does the trick.  I will study your answer a bit and try to understand it first.

Comment: don't hesitate to ask question. As you can see, there is no `groupBy`. I used a window function with a `partitionBy` which as the same role but without aggregation.

Comment: So in general I can use window functions to work over "groups" of data but when I don't necessarily want it aggregated, like with a groupby.

Do you have a good book / resource you could recommend for getting started with querying data and analysing etc?  Its something I haven't had much practice in and therefore when it comes to SQL / spark I lack some terminolgy and awareness about appraoches to problems etc.

Comment: @Aesir nothing to recommand sorry. I forged myself through my experiences. But yeah, you got the meaning.